# Export selected objects with names and dimensions to a text file

Tags: python, scripting, export

I've been looking for a way to export a Bill Of Materials from blender and found this script here in the forum. It works as it should but only exports dimensions in meters even though my blend file is set to Imperial dimensions, inches in this case.
I do not know python, is there a way to update this script to export with the current Unit System settings?

```
# import the necessary modules we need
# in our case, blender's python API and python's os module
import bpy, os

# get the current selection
selection = bpy.context.selected_objects

# initialize a blank result variable
result = ""

# iterate through the selected objects
for sel in selection:
    # get the current object's dimensions
    dims = sel.dimensions
    # write the selected object's name and dimensions to a string
    result += "%s - %.03fm x %.03fm x %.03fm\n" % (sel.name, dims.x, dims.y, dims.z)

# get path to render output (usually /tmp\)
tempFolder = os.path.abspath (bpy.context.scene.render.filepath)
# make a filename
filename = os.path.join (tempFolder, "newfile.txt")
# confirm path exists
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename), exist_ok=True)
# open a file to write to
file = open(filename, "w")
# write the data to file
file.write(result)
# close the file
file.close()
```